# Can I assume /proc will always be readable?

Tags: proc

I'm developing a script that will monitor several machines, notably by reading from `/proc/[vmstat|stat|diskstats|net/dev]` and I'm wondering if I can assume those will always be accessible and readable or if I should check whether the read went well. Any advice?

Comment: how much portability do you need? or is this only Linux?

Comment: @thrig not much. It's only Linux and every machine this is deployed on should be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot count on /proc to be there. Very security minded admins my chose not to even mount it.

But if it is there, it's quite safe to assume everybody can read it. Quite a few very common command line tools depend on /proc, (e.g. `ps`, `top`).

Comment: Okay, thanks. And if it's there, can I also assume that it will not be temporarily unavailable - even for a very improbable reason?

Comment: Are you asking me if it is probable for something very improbable to happen?

Comment: No, I'm asking if it's at all _possible_ :-)

Comment: As a linux sysadmin for over 10 years, I never saw it happen in 200+ machines. I'd say only a serious disk or admin failure, or an unlikely, big kernel bug could cause /proc to be suddenly temporarily unavailable just like that.

Comment: I saw it happen once, after not adding it to /etc/mount after installing linux compatability on a BSD (unix) server. Only time I saw it not being there though.

Comment: Not quite true, you may not be able to read the contents of `/proc/$PID` directories you don't own.  It's not common, but some people do mount `/proc` with `hidepid=1`.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelman: that, and "*[...] it will not be temporarily unavailable*" are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I should have clarified, I was commenting on the 'If it's there, it's quite safe to assume everybody can read it.' bit in the answer itself.  It's still technically safe, but you need to handle -EPERM errors correctly.